# "The name 'InitializeControl' does not exist in the current context" in Web Part with custom control

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, user-controls

I have a custom GridView control that has pagination built in it. I've used this component many times on Sharepoint 2010 without a problem. Now i'm trying to use it on a Sharepoint 2013 Web Part solution just as i did on my previous 2010 solutions and it's giving me that **"The name 'InitializeControl' does not exist in the current context"** error.

After i declare the component on my ascx, the .g.cs file goes empty and the error show up.

Here's my ascx control

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Conectt.Componentes.Noticias, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=73b1d20ea6c5bde8"
Namespace="Conectt.Componentes.Noticias" TagPrefix="Conectt" %>
<Conectt:PaginatedGrid ID="gridListagemNoticias" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gridListagemNoticias_RowDataBound"
    OnPageIndexChanging="gridListagemNoticias_PageIndexChanging" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    AllowPaging="true" UseCustomPager="true" ShowHeader="false" ShowFooter="false"
    RowStyle-CssClass="paginatedGridItem" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="paginatedGridAlternatingItem"
    ShowFirstLastArrows="true" ShowNavigationArrows="false" AllowSorting="false">
    <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <ul>
                            <li><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" /></li>
                            <li><asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" /></li>
                        </ul>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
</Conectt:PaginatedGrid>
```

And here s my paginatedgrid code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
[assembly: TagPrefix("Conectt.Componentes.Noticias", "Conectt")]
namespace Conectt.Componentes.Noticias
{
    public class PaginatedGrid : GridView
    {
        public bool UseCustomPager
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["UseCustomPager"] != null)
                    return Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["UseCustomPager"]);
                else
                    return true;
            }

            set { ViewState["UseCustomPager"] = value; }
        }

        public bool ShowNavigationArrows
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["ShowNavigationArrows"] != null)
                    return Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["ShowNavigationArrows"]);
                else
                    return true;
            }

            set { ViewState["ShowNavigationArrows"] = value; }
        }
        public bool ShowFirstLastArrows
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["ShowFirstLastArrows"] != null)
                    return Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["ShowFirstLastArrows"]);
                else
                    return false;
            }

            set { ViewState["ShowFirstLastArrows"] = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            this.CellPadding = 0;
            this.CellSpacing = 0;
            this.BorderWidth = 0;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CssClass))
                this.CssClass = "paginatedGrid";

            if (this.Width.IsEmpty)
                this.Width = new Unit("100%");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.HeaderStyle.CssClass))
                this.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "paginatedGridHeader";

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.RowStyle.CssClass))
                this.RowStyle.CssClass = "paginatedGridItem";

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass))
                this.AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass = "paginatedGridAlternatingItem";

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.PagerStyle.CssClass))
                this.PagerStyle.CssClass = "paginatedGridPager";

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.EmptyDataText))
                this.EmptyDataText = "Nenhum registro encontrado.";

            if (this.EmptyDataTemplate == null)
                this.EmptyDataTemplate = new GridViewTemplate();
        }

        protected override void InitializePager(GridViewRow row, int columnSpan, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)
        {
            if (UseCustomPager)
                CreateCustomPager(row, columnSpan, pagedDataSource);
            else
                base.InitializePager(row, columnSpan, pagedDataSource);
        }

        protected virtual void CreateCustomPager(GridViewRow row, int columnSpan, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)
        {
            int pageCount = pagedDataSource.PageCount;
            int pageIndex = pagedDataSource.CurrentPageIndex + 1;
            int pageButtonCount = 3;

            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
            if (columnSpan > 1) cell.ColumnSpan = columnSpan;

            if (pageCount > 1)
            {
                int min = pageIndex - pageButtonCount;
                int max = pageIndex + pageButtonCount;

                if (max > pageCount)
                    min -= max - pageCount;
                else if (min < 1)
                    max += 1 - min;

                HtmlGenericControl divContainer = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                divContainer.Attributes.Add("class", "paginatedGridPagesContainer");

                #region Create "First Page" and "Previous Page" button
                if (pageIndex > 1 && ShowFirstLastArrows)
                {
                    // create "first page" button
                    //cell.Controls.Add(BuildLinkButton(0, PagerButtonDirection.Prev, true, "Page", "First"));
                    divContainer.Controls.Add(BuildImageButton(0, PagerButtonDirection.Prev, "Page", "First"));
                }

                if (pageIndex > 1 && ShowNavigationArrows)
                {
                    // create "previous page" button
                    //cell.Controls.Add(BuildImageButton(0, PagerButtonDirection.Prev, "Page", "Previous"));
                    divContainer.Controls.Add(BuildImageButton(0, PagerButtonDirection.Prev, "Page", "Previous"));
                }
                #endregion

                #region Create page buttons

                bool needDiv = false;
                for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
                {
                    Control page;

                    if (i <= 2 || i > pageCount - 2 || (min <= i && i <= max))
                    {
                        string text = i.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
                        page = i == pageIndex
                                ? BuildTextSpan(text, "paginatedGridCurrentPage")
                                : BuildLinkButton(i - 1, text, "Page", text);
                        //cell.Controls.Add(page);
                        divContainer.Controls.Add(page);
                        needDiv = true;
                    }
                    else if (needDiv)
                    {
                        //cell.Controls.RemoveAt(cell.Controls.Count - 1);
                        divContainer.Controls.RemoveAt(divContainer.Controls.Count - 1);

                        page = BuildTextSpan("&hellip;", null);
                        divContainer.Controls.Add(page);
                        //cell.Controls.Add(page);
                        needDiv = false;
                    }
                }

                #endregion

                #region Create "Next Page" and "Last Page" button
                if (pageIndex < pageCount && ShowNavigationArrows)
                {
                    // create "next page" button
                    //cell.Controls.Add(BuildImageButton(pageCount, PagerButtonDirection.Next, "Page", "Next"));
                    divContainer.Controls.Add(BuildImageButton(pageCount, PagerButtonDirection.Next, "Page", "Next"));
                }

                if (pageIndex < pageCount && ShowFirstLastArrows)
                {
                    // create "last page" button
                    //cell.Controls.Add(BuildLinkButton(pageCount, PagerButtonDirection.Next, true, "Page", "Last"));
                    divContainer.Controls.Add(BuildImageButton(pageCount, PagerButtonDirection.Next, "Page", "Last"));
                }
                #endregion

                cell.Controls.Add(divContainer);
            }
        }

        #region Link Buttons
        private Control BuildLinkButton(int pageIndex, PagerButtonDirection dir, Boolean isFirstLast, string commandName, string commandArgument)
        {
            PagerLinkButton btn = new PagerLinkButton(this);
            if (isFirstLast)
                btn.ToolTip = btn.Text = dir == PagerButtonDirection.Prev ? "Primeira Página" : "Última Página";
            else
                btn.ToolTip = btn.Text = dir == PagerButtonDirection.Prev ? "Voltar Página" : "Avançar Página";
            btn.EnableCallback(ParentBuildCallbackArgument(pageIndex));
            btn.CommandName = commandName;
            btn.CommandArgument = commandArgument;
            return btn;
        }

        private Control BuildLinkButton(int pageIndex, string text, string commandName, string commandArgument)
        {
            PagerLinkButton btn = new PagerLinkButton(this);
            btn.Text = text;
            btn.ToolTip = text;
            btn.CssClass = "paginatedGridInactivePage";
            btn.EnableCallback(ParentBuildCallbackArgument(pageIndex));
            btn.CommandName = commandName;
            btn.CommandArgument = commandArgument;
            return btn;
        }

        private Control BuildTextSpan(string text, string cssClass)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cssClass)) span.Attributes["class"] = cssClass;
            span.InnerHtml = text;
            return span;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Image Buttons
        private Control BuildImageButton(int pageIndex, PagerButtonDirection dir, string commandName, string commandArgument)
        {
            PagerImageButton btn = new PagerImageButton(this);
            btn.ImageUrl = dir == PagerButtonDirection.Prev ? "/_layouts/Images/Conectt.Componentes.BuscaRamais/PaginatedGrid/paginacaoVoltarPagina.png" : "/_layouts/Images/Conectt.Componentes.BuscaRamais/PaginatedGrid/paginacaoAvancarPagina.png";
            btn.Width = 28;
            btn.Height = 28;
            btn.AlternateText = dir == PagerButtonDirection.Prev ? "Primeira Página" : "Última Página";
            btn.ToolTip = btn.AlternateText;
            btn.EnableCallback(ParentBuildCallbackArgument(pageIndex));
            btn.CommandName = commandName;
            btn.CommandArgument = commandArgument;
            return btn;
        }

        private Control BuildImageButton(int pageIndex, string text, string commandName, string commandArgument)
        {
            PagerImageButton img = new PagerImageButton(this);
            img.ImageUrl = "/_layouts/Images/Conectt.Componentes.BuscaRamais/PaginatedGrid/paginacaoMarcadorPaginaNaoAtiva.png";
            img.AlternateText = text;
            img.ToolTip = text;
            img.EnableCallback(ParentBuildCallbackArgument(pageIndex));
            img.CommandName = commandName;
            img.CommandArgument = commandArgument;
            return img;
        }

        private Control BuildImageSpan(string text, string cssClass)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cssClass)) span.Attributes["class"] = cssClass;
            span.InnerHtml = "<img src='/_layouts/Images/Conectt.Componentes.BuscaRamais/PaginatedGrid/paginacaoMarcadorPaginaAtiva.png' alt='" + text + "' title='" + text + "' />";
            return span;
        }
        #endregion

        private string ParentBuildCallbackArgument(int pageIndex)
        {
            MethodInfo m =
                typeof(GridView).GetMethod("BuildCallbackArgument", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null,
                                            new Type[] { typeof(int) }, null);
            return (string)m.Invoke(this, new object[] { pageIndex });
        }

        [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")] 
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            if (this.ShowHeader && this.Rows.Count > 0)
                writer.WriteLine("<div class='paginatedGridDestacaTitulo'>");

            base.Render(writer);

            if (this.ShowHeader && this.Rows.Count > 0)
                writer.WriteLine("</div>");
        }
    }

    public class GridViewTemplate : ITemplate
    {
        void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
        {
            Literal lit = new Literal();
            lit.Text = "<div class='PaginatedGridEmpty'>Nenhum registro encontrado.</div>";
            container.Controls.Add(lit);
        }
    }

    enum PagerButtonDirection
    {
        Prev,
        Next
    }

    public class PagerImageButton : ImageButton
    {
        public PagerImageButton(IPostBackContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public void EnableCallback(string argument)
        {
            _enableCallback = true;
            _callbackArgument = argument;
        }

        public override bool CausesValidation
        {
            get { return false; }
            set { throw new ApplicationException("Cannot set validation on pager buttons"); }
        }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            SetCallbackProperties();
            base.Render(writer);
        }

        private void SetCallbackProperties()
        {
            if (_enableCallback)
            {
                ICallbackContainer container = _container as ICallbackContainer;
                if (container != null)
                {
                    string callbackScript = container.GetCallbackScript(this, _callbackArgument);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(callbackScript)) OnClientClick = callbackScript;
                }
            }
        }

        #region Private fields

        private readonly IPostBackContainer _container;
        private bool _enableCallback;
        private string _callbackArgument;

        #endregion
    }

    public class PagerLinkButton : LinkButton
    {
        public PagerLinkButton(IPostBackContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public void EnableCallback(string argument)
        {
            _enableCallback = true;
            _callbackArgument = argument;
        }

        public override bool CausesValidation
        {
            get { return false; }
            set { throw new ApplicationException("Cannot set validation on pager buttons"); }
        }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            SetCallbackProperties();
            base.Render(writer);
        }

        private void SetCallbackProperties()
        {
            if (_enableCallback)
            {
                ICallbackContainer container = _container as ICallbackContainer;
                if (container != null)
                {
                    string callbackScript = container.GetCallbackScript(this, _callbackArgument);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(callbackScript)) OnClientClick = callbackScript;
                }
            }
        }

        #region Private fields

        private readonly IPostBackContainer _container;
        private bool _enableCallback;
        private string _callbackArgument;

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's something i'm missing on how i'm declaring the control on the page or what. Any clues on what could be happening?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problems using the SharePoint OTB SPGridView

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Ejemplos-sobre-cmo-usar-el-69cd5f16